# Can I get the tab index that was selected before

Tags: winapi, windows-10, tabcontrol, selected

The [TCM_SETCURSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcm-setcursel) message select a new tab in the control and returns the index of the previously selected one. Can I get the index of the previously selected tab index after a new one is set? for example, use jump from tab 3 (current) to 4 (new selected tab index), which fires [TCN_SELCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcn-selchange) but can I get the previous index, i.e., 3, somehow using WINAPI?

Comment: You can remember the current tab, and when you get a tab change, that variable tells you the previous tab. (Then update the variable for next time.)

Comment: Maybe you can get the index before the change by using [`TCN_SELCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcn-selchanging) and [`TabCtrl_GetCurSel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-tabctrl_getcursel).

Comment: Calling `TabCtrl_GetCurlSet` from `TCN_SELCHANGING` did the trick! Post as answer so I can accept ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the table index before changing the tab by processing the [`TCN_SELCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcn-selchanging) message and calling [`TabCtrl_GetCurSel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-tabctrl_getcursel).